# Pass Context and String to functions for MaterialPageRoute

Tags: flutter

```
    if (_seen) {
  print("Welcome back");
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
  }
```

I have a Flutter app in which I am using SharedPreferences to check if it is a users first time opening the app or not. If the variable _seen is true, it will send them to the HomeScreen. I want to do this using a function that I will have in another dart file - **functions.dart** to write cleaner code.

Can I have a function like this in functions.dart:

```
  void Navigator(context, String pageName) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => $pageName()));
  }
```

So that I can pass it like this ?

```
    if (_seen) {
  print("Welcome back");
  Navigator(context, "HomeScreen");
  }
```

Comment: instead of `Navigator(context, String pageName)` why not `Navigator(context, Widget widget)`? or use `pushReplacementNamed`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a map in `MaterialApp` that will map stringName -> Widget, and use `Navigator.pushNamed` (or similar) methods to do "navigation"

Here is how you do it:

```dart
Future<T> goToPage<T>(BuildContext context, String pageName) => Navigator.pushNamed<T>(context, pageName);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      routes: {
        "one": (context) => PageOne(),
        "two": (context)=> PageTwo(),
      },
      initialRoute: "one",
    );
  }
}

class PageOne extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("PageOne"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Go to PageTwo"),
          onPressed: ()=> goToPage(context, "two"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageTwo extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("PageTwo"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Go to PageOne"),
          onPressed: ()=> goToPage(context, "one"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```